# redirecting apache to a different module

Tags: c++, apache, apache2

i currently have an apache module which when invoked performs a number of operations one of which is to modify a URL in the form of a string. I would subsequently like to redirect to this URL. Unfortunately there is not much documentation available to help me accomplish this, can someone who has done similar please advise?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the apr_table_add function with headers_out, that holds the response headers.

```
apr_table_add(r->headers_out, "Location", your_url);

return HTTP_MOVED_PERMANENTLY;
```

Comment: this almost works however it reinvokes my module for some reason which is not what i want to do

Comment: think i have it working i was missing "http" in front of the url, thanks!